# How to label words in latex?

Tags: cross-referencing

How to label words in a latex document and use this label later on to describe the word.

For instance I want to write, [image]

and then later on I want, [image]

Comment: Are you talking about footnotes? `This document\footnote{The said document is in pdf format.} is about my research.`

Comment: Nope! `\footnote` helps to comment at the end of the same page. Instead I want to comment after my entire article is over.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to use endnotes? http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/endnotes/endnotes.pdf

Comment: Great! `\endnote` helps. But I am not getting the desired output..

Comment: Explain why, perhaps including an example with the use of `\endnote`

Comment: I'm glad we're helping, but you might need to be a bit more specific about what exactly the desired output is in that case. `This document\endnote{The said document is in pdf format.} is about my research.` With: `\usepackage{endnotes}` in the preamble and `\theendnotes` at the end of your document where you want the endnotes should work. I think you will need two passes of LaTeX. If that's the right idea but you want to tweak the style, you should reformulate the question to show exactly what you want to change. If it's the wrong idea, could you be more specific about what you want

Comment: @Au101 Instead of `3. The said document is in pdf format` , I get `3The said document is in pdf format`

Comment: `\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\theenmark. }

Comment: @Au101 A edit. The `3` is not at the same level as `T`. It is raised.

Comment: @Au101 I am sorry. I cannot follow your latest comment. Can you please be more specific. Do I still need to use the package `endnotes`?

Comment: Hm, this isn't really about footnotes, in my point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to use endnotes. I recommend the aptly-named [endnotes package](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/endnotes/endnotes.pdf) for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

This document\endnote{The said document is in pdf format.} is about my
research.

\lipsum[3]

\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\theenmark. }%
\renewcommand{\enotesize}{\normalsize}%
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

For this answer you will need `\usepackage{endnotes}` in the preamble and `\theendnotes` at the end of your document where you would like the endnotes to go.

You will also need to place the following redefinitions before `\theendnotes` to get the style you request in the question in the list of endnotes. You will need to place these after the document is finished to prevent the change being applied to the notes in the text as well.

[image]

Comment: Great! This helps!

Comment: However I did not use the `\lipsum` command. I have no idea what difference will it make..

Comment: @Qwerty `\lipsum` is for the dummy text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" etc. that you can see in the output. I used it to simulate a surrounding document and primarily to demonstrate that the endnotes are placed at the end after a document's worth of text. It's just for demonstration purposes. You should have a document where I have `\lipsum`s :P

Comment: Okay.. :) Unknowingly I get to learn another interesting thing about latex.. Thanx!!

Answer (score 2):

A very basic approach, 'exploiting' the `\@elt` list feature and LaTeX's `\@cons` macro.

In order to allow for multiple occurences of the same word, a `wordlabel` counter is stepped and the `\@currentlabel` content is written from the label description, being given as 2nd argument to the `\labelthis` macro.

The `\listoflabels` is a wrapper to traverse the `\l@b@llist` macro, all in an enumerate environment, however, there is no linking to the description list.

No other packages are needed (so far)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{wordlabel}


\makeatletter

\def\l@b@llist{}

\newcommand{\labelthis}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{wordlabel}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#2}%
  \label{#1\thewordlabel}%
  #1\textsuperscript{\number\value{wordlabel}}%
  \expandafter\@cons\csname l@b@llist\endcsname{{#1\thewordlabel}}%
}


\newcommand{\listoflabels}{%
\clearpage
\begingroup
\def\@elt##1{\item \ref{##1}}
\begin{enumerate}
\l@b@llist
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
}


\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtEndDocument{\listoflabels}
\begin{document}

This is a nice \labelthis{document}{This document is in pdf-format}.

\clearpage

But there is also something \labelthis{different}{And now for something completely different}. 


\end{document}
```

**Update with hyperlinks**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{wordlabel}


\makeatletter

\def\l@b@llist{}

\newcommand{\labelthis}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{wordlabel}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#2}%
  \label{#1\thewordlabel}%
  #1\textsuperscript{\hyperlink{link::#1\thewordlabel}{\number\value{wordlabel}}}%
  \expandafter\@cons\csname l@b@llist\endcsname{{#1\thewordlabel}}%
}


\newcommand{\listoflabels}{%
\clearpage
\begingroup
\def\@elt##1{\item \hypertarget{link::##1}{\ref{##1}}}
\begin{enumerate}
\l@b@llist
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
}


\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtEndDocument{\listoflabels}
\begin{document}

This is a nice \labelthis{document}{This document is in pdf-format}.

\clearpage

But there is also something \labelthis{different}{And now for something completely different}. 


\end{document}
```

[image]